# How can I calculate the bandwidth of the incoming compressed response to Requests object?

Tags: python, python-requests, bandwidth, urllib3

I am able to calculate the **un**compressed response using the below code:

```
headers = {
'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
'cookie': '1P_JAR=2022-01-29-22; NID=511=SULQVuezm5OrzjpKvZtmBvne4q5ZsAQS8JmtkASRvog38SdZbGgM3-Z_gD0yuk2Z1HeFpk0BLlRSoVzKWvLL1CEWlLdJs5EQun_xoY6pLotnuiuZjhlEvCkx2rJ8wbsaz6jzAl6SoAoHsEqxOviuOoaCZnAMzSf29iMM7FUlSJA; DV=c4G23wRj8NImUJHHJ0xN1v_kltiA6ldQvrLpXtnDmAQAAAA',
'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"',
'sec-ch-ua-arch': '"arm"',
'sec-ch-ua-bitness': '"64"',
'sec-ch-ua-full-version': '"97.0.4692.99"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'sec-ch-ua-model': '""',
'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
'sec-ch-ua-platform-version': '"12.0.0"',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36'    
}

r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=test&oq=test&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i271l3j69i61j69i60l2.747j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8', headers=headers)


def header_size(headers):
    return sum(len(key) + len(value) + 4 for key, value in headers.items()) + 2
 
request_line_size = len(r.request.method) + len(r.request.path_url) + 12
request_size = request_line_size + header_size(r.request.headers) + int(r.request.headers.get('content-length', 0))

response_line_size = len(r.reason) + 15
response_size = response_line_size + header_size(r.headers) + len(str(r.content))

total_size = request_size + response_size

print(total_size) # in bytes
```

In the request to Google, I get around 600 bytes. But this represents the uncompressed response on my end. Is there any way to calculate the compressed response (which is closer to 150-200 bytes in the case of Google)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`r.raw`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content) - here's a very crude example:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=test&oq=test&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i271l3j69i61j69i60l2.747j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8', headers=headers)
s = r.raw.read(100000)
print(len(s))
```

You'll have to refine this to get only the part you're interested in.

Comment: Okay this worked well, but then the problem then is that I can't access the decoded r.content which I would need for HTML parsing. Is there a way I can access r.raw without losing that?

Additionally, I think you would need to add stream=True into your answer otherwise r.raw is empty

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.